# Tuple[Any] does not satisfy Type[Any]

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I noticed that `Tuple[Any]` does not satisfy `Type[Any]`.

In python3.8...

```
var: Type[Any] = Tuple[Any]
```

When I run `mypy` against this, I get

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "object", variable has type "Type[Any]")
```

Anyone know what I may be doing wrong here? My end goal is to be able to assign `var` to `Tuple[Any, ...]`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While `Tuple[Any]` is a subtype of `Any` in the static type system, the only valid values of `Type[Any]` are actual *runtime* types, objects of type `type`. You could assign `tuple` to `var`, but not `Tuple[Any]`, since `Tuple[Any]` is not a `type`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tuple` *type hint* is not equivalent to the `tuple` *type* itself. Compare their behaviour:

```py
>>> from typing import Tuple
>>> tuple()
()
>>> Tuple()
TypeError: Type Tuple cannot be instantiated; use tuple() instead
```

As such, only `var: Type = tuple` is valid but not any variation of `var: Type = Tuple`.

---

Since Python3.9, [builtin types and their type hints are unified](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/). This allows using both interchangeably:

```py
>>> tuple[int]()
()
```

You can expect `var: Type = tuple[int]` to work once [mypy PEP 585 support is complete](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7907).